# Rotate loop retain volume

Tags: modeling, transforms, vertices, edges, topology

Do any of you know if there is a way to rotate a loop on a tube-like object while retaining it's volume. (native or add-on)

I'm aware I can just scale it on one axis after rotating to give it back its volume, but I'm wondering if there is a way to essentially rotate with a `vertex slide` type method. Making it more accurate and one step instead of two steps.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: That's should be possible with [Shear](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/shear.html) tool, but its functionality is a bit limited; it might be faster to edit that loop partially with edge slide or else something.

Comment: aha, yes, shear does seem to maintain volume but it essentially just slides both sides on one axis up or and down. So the true volume of the curve is not preserved. But thanks for pointing this out. I wasn't aware of shear.

Comment: Afaik there's no way to preserve the curvature of the curved mesh while just rotating one of the loops it consists of.. The Shear might be a bit similar functionality, not all-in-one.

Comment: Use knife or knife project (for accuracy) to establish the result.